# Maintaining continuity of animation

Tags: html, css, animation

I am trying to create an animation using css the idea is that when hovered the missile falls down(check fiddle link at bottom) rotating so that it will stay almost perpendicular 
the problem is that there is no continuity in the animation there are a few pauses i think my problem is here

```
.boy:hover~ .missile{
-webkit-animation:anim2 10s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes anim2{
0%{margin-left:280px;}
50%{margin-left:100px;}
60%{margin-top:90px;transform:rotate(200deg);}
85%{margin-left:80px; }
100%{margin-left:70px; margin-top:200px; transform:rotate(90deg);}  

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tuuqhgk3/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.boy:hover~ .missile{
  -webkit-animation:anim2 10s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
}
```

This should give you a continuous animation speed, rather than the easing (pauses) that is set by default.
Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-timing-function

Comment: For the smooth arc rotation that I think you want, check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25950360/only-certain-elements-responding-to-media-queries

They rotate around an origin, which might be easier to do (and look more natural) then trying to move the missile left+down and rotate

Answer (score 1):

Try updating your anim2 to this:

```css
@-webkit-keyframes anim2 {
    0% {margin-left: 280px; transform: rotate(220deg);}
    15% {margin-top: 80px;}
    100% {margin-left: 100px; margin-top: 200px; transform: rotate(130deg);}  
}
```

To get smooth animation, you need to calculate exact distances (margin-top, margin-left) that need to change in each % step. I don't think you need to add too many steps in this case.

Also, if you want to repeat animation, you can add "-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;" to your hover .fire/.missile (fire won't disappear, for example).

Comment: Thanks i don't want 'fire' to stay that way i just need it to remain for a few seconds that's all