# Only certain elements responding to media queries

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm working on a site and I'm trying to use multiple media queries: big screens, medium screens, small screens. I have a single stylesheet for the page and following the overall styling I enter the media queries:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1135px)
@media only screen and (min-width: 751px) and (max-width: 1134px)
@media only screen and (max-width: 750px)
```

Certain elements from the 751->1134 respond while others do not (they follow the default styling).
Nothing from the <750 changes

The elements in questions are a div with display: inline-block and elements being floated within:

```
// Default styling
div.image {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

div.text {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

// Media query #2
div.image {
  width: 40%;
  float: left;
}

div.text {
  width: 45%;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5%;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: please provide an example for elements that don't respond to the media queries and follow default styling.

Comment: I just added some. Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: Can you share a link to the page in question, or upload it to a JSFiddle? Hard to tell from what you've posted.

Comment: I actually got it working. It was an issue with caching and new resources not loading. Thank you for your help though!